# Tablas con filas expandidas

Tags: angular, table

Estoy intentando crear una tabla como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello he buscado diversos [ejemplos](https://www.uv.es/jac/guia/tablaeje.htm) en internet.

He intentado seguir el código y he conseguido lo siguiente:

```
<table>
    <tr width="35">
      <th>Columna A</th>
      <th>Columna B</th>
      <th>Columna C</th>
      <th>Columna D</th>
      <th>Columna E</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let result of Array">
      <td [attr.rowspan]="result.totalOfAnswers">{{result.infoA}}</td>
      <td [attr.rowspan]="result.totalOfAnswers">{{result.infoB}}</td>
      <td [attr.rowspan]="result.totalOfAnswers">{{result.infoC}} </td>
      <td [attr.rowspan]="result.totalOfAnswers">{{result.infoD}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let answer of result.userAnswers">{{answer}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

*La variable `totalOfAnswers` contiene `userAnswers.length` definido en el `ts`

Con este código consigo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que debo añadir otro `tr` para iterar el segundo `*ngFor`, pero si hago esto, pierdo el valor de `result.answer` (iterado en el primer `tr`) ya que debo cerrar entonces el primer `tr`.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas haciendo el for sobre el `TD` por lo que estas agregando mas columnas de las que declaras.

Para hacer que queden una debajo de la otra reemplaza

```
<td *ngFor="let answer of result.userAnswers">{{answer}}</td>
```

por una lista dentro del TD

```
<td>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let answer of result.userAnswers">{{answer}}</li>
</ul>
</td>
```

Comment: Me sirve! He quitado el `<li>` y he iterado sobre el `<ul>` para quitar los "puntos" de indexado. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, no elimines las `<li>`. El tag de html `<ul>` indica que es un listado y los tag `<li>` de su interior indican los diferentes items del listado. Para quitar los puntos puedes utilizar el CSS `style-decoration:none`.